# El capitan not installing

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

I have file vault and a firmware password on my laptop. 
I have 13.14 gigs of space left on my drive after deleting a few things which should be enough.

this is on a 15 inch mid 2014 mac book pro.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A system restart resolved the issue, you can install this beta with a firmware password and file vault enabled.

Just a heads up to anyone wanting to test the public beta. A number of applications that run system daemons do not work on 10.11. I am personally downgrading back to a stable release until more developers update their applications.